# Can't setState in touchablehighlight onpress

Tags: react-native

When I try to set the state in touchablehighlight onpress my app crashes. This is what I got:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.setState({toggleCharacter: false})}>
    <Image style={styles.tekstballon} source={tekstballon} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

My ultimate goal is to toggle `toggleCharacter` so if it is false I want to set it to true and if it's true I want to set it to false but I am not sure how to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're invoking that setState call immediately on render. You need to wrap it in a function that will be called on onPress instead, ie:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({toggleCharacter: false})}>
```

Keep in mind, the above is a bit frowned upon as it's creating a new function for every instance but it's just meant to give you an idea of why you're getting your error (a bit more performant to add it to the class itself.)

Edited to answer comment. The 'better' way of doing it mentioned above would be:

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {

  /*
    ...ctor and methods above
    The below assumes Property initializer syntax is available.
    If not, you need to autobind in the constructor
  /*
  handleOnPress = () => this.setState({ toggleCharacter: false })

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleOnPress}>
        <Image style={styles.tekstballon} source={tekstballon} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works but I don't understand how exactly I could do it better. Should I create a function outside of the render and call it in the onPress?

Comment: See comment above, but essentially yes, you'll just pull it out into being a method on the class itself.